# What do metadata-agent health errors in GKE logs mean?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I setup a standard GKE cluster including istio. In the logs I find errors among which e.g.:

```
{
 insertId:  "xuxoovg5olythg"  
 logName:  "projects/projectname/logs/stderr"  
 metadata: {…}  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-01-03T11:39:10.996283280Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   cluster_name:  "standard-cluster-1"    
   container_name:  "metadata-agent"    
   location:  "europe-west4-a"    
   namespace_name:  "kube-system"    
   pod_name:  "metadata-agent-859mq"    
   project_id:  "myprojectname"    
  }
  type:  "k8s_container"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "W0103 11:39:06 7fc26c8bf700 api_server.cc:183 /healthz returning 500; unhealthy components: Pods
"  
 timestamp:  "2019-01-03T11:39:06Z"  
}
```

Is this a problem? What to do with this?

Comment: I recommend contacting Google Cloud support about this. Are you seeing any functional degradation? It might be just intermittent failures which can be ok.

Comment: As Ahmet above recommended you can reach out to [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/) directly or if you believe this might be an issue with the product you can file an issue directly through the Public issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is said to be working as intended, as a short-term solution. Possibly will be fixed in the future.

Source: https://github.com/Stackdriver/metadata-agent/issues/183#issuecomment-426406327